# Convert Excel power query table column to string

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying to make my power query more dynamic, currently I request my data using a stored procedure including part-no parameter that I hard-code into my query

```
EXEC GSCM_Staging.dbo.top_N_BOM 
    @Top_Parts = 'GL158K380G03|GL302K479G02|GL825R339G06|GL825R367G03|GL212R585G06'
```

I already have the individual part numbers in a list from a table in Excel

[image]

How would I go about converting this column with 4 rows into a column with a single pipe delimited row (Like the one used in my SQL query)

Comment: Found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33111443/convert-column-to-cell-string-power-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fairly easy

Beginning from your `Source` table

1. first convert the table to list

   ```
   ListOfParts = Source[TOP_PART]
   ```
2. then concatenate the list into delimited text

   ```
   JoinedText = Text.Combine(ListOfParts, "|")
   ```
3. further modify it if required

   ```
   PartsFilter = "'" & JoinedText "'"
   ```

In short

```
let
    Source = Table.CurrentWorkbook.....
    ListOfParts = Source[TOP_PART]
    JoinedText = Text.Combine(ListOfParts, "|")
    PartsFilter = "'" & JoinedText "'"
in PartsFilter
```